# I can't connect new Windows 7 PC to Mac iBook with OS 10.3.9

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, connection

Help !

I have an old iBook wired to a router and a new PC linking wirelessly to same router. On the Mac I have 'seen' the PC but not been able to connect to it.

On the PC, the Network and Sharing Centre lists 'IBOOK'. When I click on this, 'Windows Security' asks me to 'Enter Network Password', asking for User name and password.

I have tried:

1) The user name and password of my admin account on the iBook. This returns a 'logon failure' message but lists the user name as [NAME_OF_PC\User Name], suggesting it was looking for the user name of the PC, not the Mac.

2) The user name and password of my account on the PC. This also returns a 'logon failure' message.

3) The user name of my account on the PC and the 'homegroup password' given to me by Windows when setting up the PC. This also returns a 'logon failure' message.

Today I've tried connecting the two machines via a patch cable - still no joy.

Can anyone help? It is 20 years since I wrestled with any OS other than Mac, and 10 years since I've done mich wrangling with the Macs, so please assume no knowledge!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac navigate to

System Preferences -> Sharing -> File Sharing

and make sure File Sharing is checked. The actual path to File Sharing may be slightly different as I am looking at a 10.6.x machine. This should allow you to connect from the Win 7 machine.

Also, if you want to connect to a 10.3 machine with Ethernet, you will need a [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable), not a straight patch cable.

Comment: Thanks very much, Casey. I'll get a crossover cable and try again. The Windows PC came with a Firewall installed. Could this be a problem?

Comment: You'll only need the Crossover cable if you connect the two computers directly.. And yes, the Windows firewall may be a problem as well.